# If a group has the element $a^3$ than will it have the element $a$?

Tags: group-theory

Is it necessary that if a subgroup $G$ of a group $H$ has a element $a^3$, $a^3\in G$, then it will have the element $a$? That is, does the following implication hold?
$$
a^3\in G\Rightarrow a\in G
$$

Comment: Where is $a$ living? If you consider that $G$ is a subgroup of a group $H$, the answer is no. Consider $H=\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$, $G = \{0,3\}$ and $a=1$.

Answer (score 7):

No. For instance, let G be the multiplicative group over $\mathbb Q-\{0\}$, and take $a = \sqrt[3]2$.

Answer (score 4):

No. Let $H$ be a group and let $a\in H$ be an element of $H$ order $n$ where $n$ is *not coprime* to $3$ (and $n$ is possibly infinite). If $G=\langle a^3\rangle$ is the subgroup generated by $a^3$ then $a\not\in G$.

For example, let $H=\langle a\rangle$ be the group which acts on a hexagon by rotation. Then $a^3$ is a half-turn and clearly $a$ is not contained in $G=\langle a^3\rangle$. (Here $H=\langle a\rangle$ is cyclic of order $6$ while $G=\langle a^3\rangle$ is cyclic of order $2$.)

Another example would be to take the infinite cyclic group $C_{\infty}=\langle a\rangle$. This is isomorphic to the integers under addition, but is written multiplicatively. Then $\langle a^3\rangle\cong \langle a\rangle$ but clearly $a\not\in \langle a^3\rangle$ (as otherwise, working modulo $3$ would be the same as working modulo $0$...!).